# Angular ui router view loaded but not passing parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on a website with angular ui-router. There is a page which needs to pass some parameters to another view. I defined my states like this:

```
.state('locaties', {
            url: "/locaties",
            data: {rule: function($cookieStore) {} },
            controller: "FranchisesCtrl",
            templateUrl: "view/locaties.html"
        })
            .state('locaties.detail', {
                params: {
                    locatieID: 1,
                    locatieName: "Derptown",
                    locatieLat: 50,
                    locatieLong: 50
                },
                url: "/:locatieName",
                controller: "LocatieDetailCtrl",
                templateUrl: "view/locatie.html",
                resolve: {
                    locatiedetail:
                        function ($stateParams, $http){
                            var url ="http://website/api/franchises/" + $stateParams.locatieID + "/nl.json";
                            return $http.get(url).then(function(res){
                                return res.data;
                            });
                        }
                }
            })
```

Inside LocatieDetailCtrl there's this

```
angular.module('PremiumMeat').controller('FranchisesDetailCtrl', 
  function ($scope, $window, franchisedetail) {
    $scope.franchiseDetail = franchisedetail;
  });
```

The "Locaties" (plural) view works properly and when I click on a specific "locatie" (single), the url changes and the view gets loaded within the locaties view and no parameters are passed. On the image you can see the top 2 items from the "locaties" view. Then a single locatie is loaded under the "locaties" view. This should be a new page (view) with the parameters from the clicked locatie. Can anyone help me / explain, I'm rather new to angular, thank you.

[image: views]

Comment: Can you post the templates?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

The parameters where hard-coded, to make them dynamic, syntax needed adjustment according to [angular docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider).

```
params: {
                    locatieID: {value : "1"},
                    locatieName: {value : "Stad"},
                    locatieDescr: {value : "Beschrijving"},
                    locatieLat: {value: 51.2},
                    locatieLong: {value : 4.4}
                },
```

Where parameters are passed with ui-href like this

```
<a ui-sref="locaties.detail({
                locatieID: item.id,
                locatieName: item.name,
                locatieDescr: item.description,
                locatieLat: item.location[0].lat,
                locatieLong: item.location[0].long
            })"
            class="detail">Bekijk detail >></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'params' defined should return the key-value pair object.

But it is a better practice if you are passing values from one state to another to use 'data' instead of appending everything in the URL.

The following code should work :

```
//The following values are default values of the parameters
.state('locaties.detail', {
                params: {
                    locatieID: '1',
                    locatieName: 'Derptown',
                    locatieLat: '50',
                    locatieLong: '50'
                }, ........
```

This should work. The values expected are of string type and not number.

As far as your LocatieDetailCtrl is concerned, you need to inject what you have in the resolve of the 'locaties.detail' state (i.e. 'locatiedetail'). So your 'LocatieDetailCtrl' should look like following:

```
angular.module('PremiumMeat').controller('FranchisesDetailCtrl', 
  function ($scope, $window, franchisedetail, locatiedetail) {
    $scope.franchiseDetail = franchisedetail; //make sure you have franchiseDetail as well.
    $scope.locatiedetail = locatiedetail; 
  });
```

I hope that will work.